# WoW always re-downloads itself after every start

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Okay, this is really annoying. This is a fresh copy of WoW, just downloaded it.
Every time I restart the Launcher (e.g.: quit from game and start it again), it starts to download everything from the "Available" part.

So, after every restart, I have 5.6gb to re-download. Not really convenient with cable.
(I tried the repair tool, but it only checked the `wow.exe` and said everything is OK.)

Comment: if I remove all the caches, the game starts right up. (after a short "applying non-critical patches"). how? why?

Comment: of course, this means I lose every setting, addon and everything else at every start.

Comment: Are you running the launcher as an administrator? Are you letting it finish the download, applying all the updates and then shutting down your computer? If you don't let it finish it will always try to complete the next time you launch. But it should redownload the data (unless you are using a non admin account that wipes the data when you log off).

Comment: I have let it download until it shown the "client ready" message. I don't have a firewall, and yes I ran it as administrator.

Comment: Now I started playing after clearing the cache, and I saw the "Game is downloading" at the UI. It started from 67%. After the first few quests, it was at 72% and the game disconnected after I had to wait for like 5 minutes at a loading screen. Weird.

Comment: So far you haven't confirmed that you have let it fully complete without interrupting the download/updating. Have you tried just loading the launcher, letting the download/updating complete, exit the launcher (so it commits the changes) then starting the game again?

Comment: Yes, and it says it's complete, and the client is ready Sorean. Until I start the game. If I start it, I lose my game content. Now I'm letting it download again. Again.

Comment: Is your world of warcraft folder properties set to "Read-Only"?

Comment: Nope, didn't touch it. I already opened a ticket once I could get in game, wonder if they know the answer. The forum answers at Blizzard were pretty lame. Uninstall/reinstall. :/

Comment: I'm out of ideas then. Please let us know your resolution when you get this figured out.

Comment: It may be helpful to mention in the question where/how you got the "fresh copy" (I'm assuming the official Battle.net site, yeah?)

Comment: @Jeroen - Yes, it was a complete fresh copy from Battle.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that installer will report you that the game is downloaded, everything is fine.

But after your first login (and log out), it will start downloading, again.
I think this is due to the Cataclysm/WoTLK content which some of the people may not have.

But that's only a simple assumption. So if it starts downloading again, let it download. It can do it in-game, but it needs some speedy net connection for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, albeit with the MoP beta.  As lame as it may be, it fixed itself when I re-installed it as part of upgrading my PC.

Having said that, you can play WoW without running it through the launcher (at least until the next patch).  If you go to the folder WoW is installed on your PC and create a shortcut to the WoW.exe file, run that shortcut and it won't run the launcher so it won't try to re-download multiple gigabytes of files.  I used this workaround for a while when I was having this issue.